# Google Analytics API returns usageLimitsuserRateLimitExceededUnregUser

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

Google Analytics API has always returned correct figures, but right now, following error is occuring more often:

*GAPI: Failed to request report data. Error: "usageLimitsuserRateLimitExceededUnregUser Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign uphttps://code.google.com/apis/console"*

As we know, google analytics API returns 50k free quote per day, but my script does not produce more than 1k requests per day, and yet, i'm receiving this error.

I've activated "Google Analytics" from code.google.com/apis/console, but when i looking "quotas" tab there is still Billing status = billing is not enabled.

I'm using php interface (http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/)

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Are you sure they didn't skip the API (with a newer version), they've done this before with Google Maps.

Comment: I'm having the same problem today.  Did they dump the old API?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and got rid of it by deliberately slowing down the request rate by a second or two.

What I assumed (please correct me if I am wrong) is that this error also comes up when the requests are being issued very fast from the client.

My logic goes like this:

1.Issue a request
 2.Process the data from the response
 3.Wait a second or two (let google server pant.. huff huff.... :P)
 4.Repeat steps 1-4 till the task is done.

Comment: I tried this, but its not working in function protected function authenticateUser($email, $password)
$post_variables = array(
   'accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
   'Email' => $email,
   'Passwd' => $password,
   'setDeveloperKey'=>'abcdogjdsighsklghksdkgj',
   'source' => gapi::interface_name,
   'service' => 'analytics'
  );

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the problem via using google's (google-api-php-client) php library.

Comment: Could you please specify your solution?

Comment: 1. create a new project
2. the first think you need to enable "google analytics" from code.google.com/apis/console.
3. create oAuth2.0 and using this in php. After that i will not get this error ever.